# Test if intercepts in ancova model are significantly different in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-test, ancova

I ran a model explaining the weight of some plant as a function of time and trying to incorporate the treatment effect.

```
mod <- lm(weight ~time + treatment)
```

The model looks like this:

[image]

with model summary being:

```
Call:
lm(formula = weight ~ time + treatment, data = df)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-21.952  -7.674   0.770   6.851  21.514 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -37.5790     3.2897 -11.423  < 2e-16 ***
time          4.7478     0.2541  18.688  < 2e-16 ***
treatmentB    8.2000     2.4545   3.341  0.00113 ** 
treatmentC    5.4633     2.4545   2.226  0.02797 *  
treatmentD   20.3533     2.4545   8.292 2.36e-13 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 9.506 on 115 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7862,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7788 
F-statistic: 105.7 on 4 and 115 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

ANOVA table

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: weight
           Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
time        1 31558.1 31558.1 349.227 < 2.2e-16 ***
treatment   3  6661.9  2220.6  24.574 2.328e-12 ***
Residuals 115 10392.0    90.4
```

I want to test the H0 that intercept1=intercept2=intercept3=intercept4. Is this done by simply interpreting the t-value and p-value for the intercept ( I guess not because this is the baseline (treatment A in this case))? I'm a bit puzzled by this as not much attention is paid on difference in intercept on most sources i looked up.

Comment: The different intercepts are modeled by the treatment variable.

Comment: what you are looking for is the treatment row in the anova table. If intercept1=intercept2 ... the amount of variance explained by treatment will be close to zero

Comment: Thanks a lot. And the amount of variance explained by treatment would be close to zero if the intercepts do not significantly differ from each other right?

Comment: yes exactly. you can also use glht from multcomp to perform comparisions between each levels of treatment

Comment: Thanks so much, its clear to me now.